# Read a live log file

Tags: java, file, logging

What would be a good way to read new entries in a text file that is continuously getting updated by another thread without having too much system strain?

- Only new entries are being appended that I want to read line by line, process them, and then output them in a new file.
- The log file could grow a few GBs big and have around 5 million lines before being deleted.
- Both the log file and this code will run on 64-bit Windows 7 with Java 7 (if that matters).

I am very new to programming, so would someone be willing to provide some sample code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Commons has a [Tailer](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) class.

Other than that, I guess you could open a BufferedReader, and sleep if readLine comes back null (in other words, the end of the file has been reached).

But the Apache Tailer class is much better, handles rolling log files and such.